# Find actual screen resolution (not CSS pixels, real screen) with javascript

Tags: javascript

These days there's a big difference between pixels and points (CSS pixels, DIPS). On my particular computer its the same, but on retina macs and a lot of phones, there's 4 or 8 pixels per point. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

> That is, the “pixels” that are used in CSS declarations such as width: 300px or font-size: 14px,have nothing to do with the actual pixel density of the device, or even with the rumoured upcoming intermediate layer. They’re essentially an abstract construct created specifically for us web developers.

I want to get the screen resolution (the real screen resolution, you get it by now), and then serve an image scaled to maximally fill the screen. This means no need to get 2000x2000 pixels images on mobile devices, while still getting good resolutions on a large mac. 
Hover, when using `screen.height` it returns CSS pixels not the screen resolution, meaning a retina mac will get an image that is half the size of the screen, resulting in pixelation. Any way to get the actual screen resolution, or the pixels-to-points ratio in javascript?

Comment: It returns the height in pixels, not points... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/height

Comment: that is because it is what we call pixels in the web world, but it is actualy fake pixels or points. CSS pixels they are also called

Comment: screen.height is also subject to change if you zoom

Comment: No, you're mistaken.  I don't know where you're getting that information from but it's incorrect.

Comment: zoom in on this page and reload http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-monitor-screen-resolution-javascript you will see it change when you zoom (and reload)

Comment: I did it on this page, before I responded to you.  It was the same both at 100% and fully zoomed.

Comment: it isnt for me in firefox

Comment: screen.height should be the pixel height of your monitor, regardless of anything else.  I think you've found a problem elsewhere if you're getting incorrect values.  I'll try it in Firefox as well

Comment: also because of the answer below it will still return half on a mac

Comment: It does indeed change in Firefox - you're right.  Not sure what to say about that as it clearly shouldn't.  On the developer docs it says that IE may show an incorrect value, due to zoom, but doesn't mention Firefox.

Comment: but even if it worked corectly it is not the right thing. cause it is talking about CSS pixels: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html i need to get the actual pixels on the screen

Comment: I get the resolution of my screen, zoomed and not zoomed it does not change and it is correct.  I think your problem is specific to a scenario, rather than something everyone will see.  I can't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Actually, that article is talking about screen media sizes, which are a completely different thing.  The viewport meta tag will affect the css screen size by applying a pixel density.  For example, my HTC has a screen width of 1080 pixels (when in portrait), but if you apply the viewport meta tag then it treats it as 480 pixels.  i think the problem here may not be the problem you think.

Comment: yes that is correct, i need the 1080 pixels not the 480. I am asking how i can get those

Comment: I was wrong - mine shows as 360px.  Either way, I've added an answer that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the actual screen height, regardless of pixel density which is altered by including the viewport tag...

```
screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio
```

Answer (score 0):

Macs with retina renders pages in 2x scale, and so `screen.height` returns actual height divided by 2. See answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/why-do-browsers-not-render-pictures-in-native-pixel-density-on-retina-display)

Comment: but if i render an image that is 2000x2000 at 1000x1000 on a mac it will display all 2000 pixels. But with my system it would only get an image that is 1000x1000, cause that is what screen.height reports

Comment: to clearify, i want to not get the one divided by 2, but the real one. however i never know when it is divided and when its not